# How to find DirectX loctation for d3dx9.h error

Tags: c++, path, directx, directx-9

I don't nnow the location of my DirectX so is there a wway to find it?

I need it for fixing this : #include <d3dx9.h> error

Comment: Make sure you [download the SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=6812) if you haven't. I don't see why you'd need to go searching after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `d3dx9.h` legacy utility library for Direct3D 9 is *only* available in the DirectX SDK. June 2010 is the last release of the DirectX SDK and is on [Microsoft Downloads](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812)--although not for long [per this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4472027/2019-sha-2-code-signing-support-requirement-for-windows-and-wsus).

Note that with Visual C++ 2012 or later, you must take special care when referencing the legacy DirectX SDK include/lib paths because they contain headers older than the Windows 8.x SDK/Windows 10 SDK used by Visual C++ so they can cause conflicts. Details on covered at the bottom of [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-).

> D3DX9, D3DX10, D3DX11, and the DirectX SDK are all deprecated. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/).

The general recommendation is to NOT use Direct3D 9 at all and instead use Direct3D 11 or later. All required Direct3D includes/libs for DirectX 11 & DirectX 12 are included in the Windows SDK.

For a list of modern replacements for the contents in the old D3D9X/D3DX10/D3DX11 utility libraries, see [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/living-without-d3dx/).